# How do I automatically give my players the USER role when they join my MC server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

newbie here at running a server. I'm not sure how to automatically put new players into the USER group (I have Admin, Mod, and User), and so far I've had to do it by hand (lp user [Username] group user set) with LuckPerms. It's kinda tedious.

If I don't do this, new players don't have any perms, so it's important that they get added to that group. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Does that mod allow selectors like "`@a`"?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried typing it in the console and nothing happened. I tried typing it in chat and it just went through as normal text (Probably obvious, oops)

Comment: Also-Luckperms is a plugin for sponge (I only have that program so I can run Mods and Plugins on my server).
Luckperms may be a little janky. I'm having to set permissions by hand in the console for everything and for all three groups. When I started, I was unable to change the time or gamemode. Had to give myself perms for that (OP {Username] did nothing)

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with LuckPerms, but what I understand from the [default groups wiki page on github](https://github.com/lucko/LuckPerms/wiki/Default-Groups), is that luckperms automatically assigns the group default to a user (correct me if I'm wrong.) However, there is a way to take away this group, and replace it with another in your `luckperms.conf`.

```
default-assignments:
  my-defaults-rule:
    if:
      has-true: <group.default>
    take:
      - group.default
    give:
      - group.user
    set-primary-group: user
```

In my opinion (looking at the github wiki), LuckPerms is very overpowered for what I think you are trying to achieve on your server. Perhaps take a look at [PermissionsEX](https://forums.spongepowered.org/t/permissionsex-v2-0-api-5/6198)

Answer (score 0):

use '/lp group default setdisplayname ' to default your players to a name you choose.

more reference [here](https://luckperms.net/wiki/Default-Groups)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).